# if $c+q\in \Bbb R$and $cq\in \Bbb R$ then $|c-4q|^2=|c|^2-8|c||q|+16|q|^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Determine the statement is true or false.

(#) For any $c,q\in \Bbb C,$ if $c+q\in \Bbb R$and $cq\in \Bbb R$ then $|c-4q|^2=|c|^2-8|c||q|+16|q|^2$.

(*) There exists some $p\in \Bbb C$ \ {-$i$} such that (for any $a\in R, |p+i|\leq(a+2)^2$.

1. For (#), I think of using parallelogramic identity and get $|c-4q|^2=2|c|^2+2(16)|q|^2-|c+4q|^2$. But I get stuck here, how can I make use of $c+q\in \Bbb R$and $cq\in \Bbb R$ to continue the proof? Or any other ways I should approach?
2. For (*), I have no clues on how to start. If I apply parallelogramic identity, I get $2|p|^2+2|i|^2-|p-i|^2$ for the LHS, and $(a+2)^4$ on RHS. I get stuck here.

The two statements are not related to each other, and I am new to learn proving statements. Plz give me some hints. Many thanks!

Comment: Hints: 1) write it as $\,|c-4q|^2=\left(|c|-4|q|\right)^2\,$ and think triangle inequality, 2) the inequality would have to hold for all $a$, so it must also hold for the $a$ that minimizes $(a+2)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\underline{\text{Question 1}}$.

> if $c+q\in \Bbb R$and $cq\in \Bbb R$ then $|c-4q|^2=|c|^2-8|c||q|+16|q|^2$?

Assume that $(a + ib) = c, (x + iy) = q.$

Since $c + q \in \Bbb{R},$ you have that 
$y = -b \implies q = (x - ib).$

Then, since $cq \in \Bbb{R},$ you have that 
$(a + ib)(x - ib) \in \Bbb{R} \implies b(x - a) = 0.$

In order for the assertion to be true, it must be true both when $b = 0$ and when $b \neq 0,$ which implies that $x = a.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1} ~b = 0}$. 
Then $c = a, q = x.$ 
Then $|c - 4q|^2 = |(a - 4x)^2| = |a^2 - 8ax + 16x^2|.$

$|c|^2 - 8|c||q| + 16|q|^2$ 
$= ~a^2 - 8|ax| + 16x^2.$

The assertion fails here, because $(ax)$ might be negative.

As a simple example, consider $c = 1, q = -2.$ 
Then $|c - 4q|^2 = |9|^2 = 81.$

$|c|^2 - 8|c||q| + 16|q|^2 $ 
$= ~1 - 8(1)(2) + 16(4) = 65 - 16 \neq 81.$

In and of itself, the failure in Case 1 is sufficient to conclude that the assertion is false.

However, the problem composer may have intended that the possibility of $c$ and $q$ both being Real was to be excluded.  In any event, Case 2 is also worth exploring.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2} ~a = x}$. 
So, in this case, $c$ and $q$ are any two complex conjugates. 
So, $c = (a + ib), q = (a - ib).$ 
Then $|c - 4q|^2 = |-3a + i5b|^2 = 9a^2 + 25b^2.$

$|c|^2 = (a^2 + b^2).$ 
$8|c||q| = 8\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = 8(a^2 + b^2).$ 
$16|q|^2 = 16(a^2 + b^2).$

Therefore, $|c|^2 - 8|c||q| + 16|q|^2$ 
$= 17(a^2 + b^2) - 8(a^2 + b^2) = 9(a^2 + b^2) $ 
$\neq (9a^2 + 25b^2).$

Therefore, the assertion also fails to be generally true in this case.

---

$\underline{\text{Question 2}}$. 
According to the assertion, some specific satisfying $p = x+iy$ must exist, where $(x,y) \neq (0,-1).$

This implies that, in order to **try to defeat** the assertion, you are allowed to select $a$, **after** $p$ is selected.

$\displaystyle |p + i| = |x + i(y+1)| = \sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2}.$

Choose 
$\displaystyle a = -2 + \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} \implies $

$\displaystyle (a + 2)^2 = \left[\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right]^2 = \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{4}$.

What the above analysis demonstrates is that if $p$ is any value with its Real component, $x$, not equal to $0$, then the assertion can be defeated by a proper choice of $a$.

Therefore, in order to demonstrate that the assertion can be completely defeated, you have to demonstrate that it can be defeated when $x = 0.$

So, by assumption $p = iy, ~y \neq -1.$

Then $p + i = i(y+1) \neq 0$ and $|p+i| = \sqrt{(y+1)^2} = |y+1| > 0.$

Simplest to defeat the assertion in this case, is to choose $a = -2$, so that $(a+2)^2 = 0.$

More interesting is trying to defeat the assertion with some value of $a$ other than $a = -2.$

Choose $\displaystyle a = -2 + \frac{\sqrt{|1 + y|}}{2}.$

Then $\displaystyle (a + 2)^2 = \frac{|1 + y|}{4},$ 
which also defeats the assertion.